# Vectors $a,b$ and $c$ are linearly independent. Does that mean $a,a+b$ and $a+b+c$ are also LI?

Tags: linear-algebra

If vectors $a, b$ and $c$ are linearly independent (LI), how do I show $a, a+b, a+b+c$ are also LI?

I am not sure my solution is correct but if we assume they are LI, that means

$xa+y(a+b)+z(a+b+c)=0$ then $x,y$ and $z$ equal to $0$.

Let's change things about and write:

\begin{align}
& \ xa+ya+yb+za+zb+zb=0 \\
\Rightarrow & \ a(x+y+z)+b(y+z)+zb=0
\end{align}

Putting back $x = y = z = 0$, then indeed they are LI.

I would love to hear if that way is legit and if not - a better more elegant way to solve it.

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/588038

Answer (score 1):

I think you need an extra step.
After $a(x+y+z)+b(y+z)+cz=0$ you can conclude $x+y+z=y+z=z=0$ because $a,b,c$ are LI.  Then solve the three equations to get $x=y=z=0$